# Type guards to convert interface X into Required<X>?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `Foo` with an optional field and want to call a function that takes `Required<Foo>`. Is there a type-safe way of calling this function? For example

```
interface FooBar {foo:string, bar?: string}

const myFooBar:FooBar = {foo:'foo'}
if (myFooBar.bar !== undefined) {
    test(myFooBar)
}

function test(fooBar: Required<FooBar>) {
    console.log(fooBar.bar)
}
```

but the compiler reports

```
Argument of type 'FooBar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Required<FooBar>'.
  Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

I could just myFooBar explicitly but does anyone know of a type-safe of doing this that doesn't involve casting.

Link to playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CE5WQbxkwC4BnMKUAcwBpkAjXAfmOXMpCoF8AoHhdCHLIAtgE8M2XMUk48AXgJF0xAOTLVvYDGQAKcbNwA6RngCE8xQFcQAEwgxQEWwEoCPZJ+SRy+iZjkXHl4eGBsEMGBBbwhfZTlWACUIAEcrYChnAB5DKAA+N3wPLwEhdAAbCCNy9CpdeONTIN4gA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#user-defined-type-guard-functions) for that:

```typescript
function hasBar(fooBar: FooBar): fooBar is Required<FooBar> {
    return typeof myFooBar.bar !== "undefined";
}
```

Then

```typescript
if (hasBar(myFooBar)) {
    test(myFooBar)
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CE5WQbxkwC4BnMKUAcwBpkAjXAfmOXMpCoF8AoHmAK4gEYYOhDIAFnFI4oACiLZcrDMqgBKVkrnJgpZACUIARwHAoEACYAeNXIB8BHslfJLYAVAlgAngAcIdBhkAFtfe1wAOkY8AEIAXgTkACIhKwgYUGsUgG4eXh4EcXIwiMw5Yki8ZMISAHIlet5gEPlpWVx5cOqNDWc3ZEhybvL1DQK+QWFRcSGIEZ0VI1NzS1tqh378FzdikFJ0ABsIKKP0KkUK6NiJ3iA)

It doesn't have to be so specific to the `FooBar` type if you don't want it to be. It could be specific to the fact that `bar` is type `string`:

```typescript
function hasBarString<T>(fooBar: T): fooBar is T & {bar: string} {
    return typeof myFooBar.bar === "string";
}

const myFooBar:FooBar = {foo:'foo'}
if (hasBarString(myFooBar)) {
    test(myFooBar)
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CE5WQbxkwC4BnMKUAcwBpkAjXAfmOXMpCoF8AoHmAK4gEYYOhDIAFnFI4oAZQrUAPABUAfAAoi2XK1UBKVjrnJgpZKuQAyAoyit21LgR7J3yKBDACoEsACeAA4Q6DDIALYBGLpQAHT2yAC8KcgARE6caQDcPLw8COLkkdGYcsQxpkkEOsQA5Dp1vMDhmtKyuIocVJpRlbgGBq4eyJDkvaWxBnl8gsKi4qMQ4yZ6yABKEACOAsBeACbK-VDqQ-huHoUgpOgANhBxt+g9q-H207xAA)

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at that code knowing there must be a good way of doing it